# How to use a column as a condition. Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to reduce a column by using a condition previously applied on the same column. The condition im using are dates (between current_date - interval ('1 month') and current_date). The column im looking for are ids, in oder to see the ids of people who used an app in a period of time and then take this ids out of the overall id columnn. This will show me the ids of people who havent used the app in the last month.

```
with t as(
          select id as active_id
          from table1
          where last_interaction between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date
          group by id)

select id
from table1 
join t
on t.active_id = table1.id
where table1.id != t.active_id
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want from just one English sentence and one partial SQL query. Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sample data and desired results might give some idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, please. No images.)

Comment: Can we have Yiyi an exqample of condition you have in mind?

Comment: The condition im using are dates (between current_date - interval ('1 month') and current_date). The column im looking for are ids, in oder to see the ids of people who used an app in a period of time and then take this ids out of the overall id columnn. This will show me the ids of people who havent used the app in the last month.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call what you are looking for a 'Find Unmatched' query.  You want to find all the things in a table which don't match the results of another query.  To do this, you do a LEFT JOIN between the main table and the 'filter table.'  This will put t.xy's value in the t.xy column when there IS a match and it will put NULL in t.xy when there IS NOT a match.

From there, you just want to have a WHERE t.xy IS NULL so that you only get back t.x's where there was no t.xy.

```
with t as(
          select x as xy
          from table1
          where x between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date
          group by x)

select x
from table1 
LEFT join t
on t.xy = table1.x
where t.xy IS NULL
```

I also fixed a typo where you had `table.x` instead of `table1.x`.

Comment: Many thanks. "where t.xy IS NULL" was what i was looking for.